# How to reduce the width of Window 10 Taskbar buttons to display only the app icon followed by 3-4 characters of app title?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

This is in reference to [this tutorial on tenforums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104754-change-width-taskbar-buttons-windows.html) which explains how to reduce the width of the taskbar buttons.

I had followed the same tutorial in Windows 7 and was able to reduce the size of the taskbar buttons to appear like this:

[image]

As you can see, the taskbar buttons would display only the app icon followed by 2-4 characters of app title, followed by the three dots. That was it. This was the case even when the taskbar was almost empty (i.e., when it had only 1-2 app buttons to show).

But I'm unable to achieve the same result in Windows 10. Kindly suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

No idea, I test on my Windows 10 machine, same result.

If taskbar buttons don’t fill the taskbar, they will show the complete state, in Windows 10, the minimum value of MinWidth string value is 38, I modify it as 18, no effect, only bigger than 38 can task effect. It should be by design

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for confirming my issue.
Let's see if someone else came up with some tweak. :)